doubt regarding the implied meaning of a line in Thomas calculus book.
In example 1 on page 2 of chapter 1 of the thirteenth edition of the book "Thomas' Calculus" the author is discussing about the domain and range of the function y=x2.The text is as follows: "The formula y =x2 gives a real y-value for any real number x, so the domain
is  (−∞,∞). The range of y = x2 is [0,∞) because the square of any real number is non
negative and every nonnegative number y is the square of its own square root, y=(√
y)2
for y>=0".
In the above lines the author has clearly given the explanation of the reason as to why the range is [0,∞).However I am unable to understand the significance of the line "every nonnegative number y is the square of its own square root, y=(√
y)2
for y>=0." in this context of finding the range of the function. Was this line necessary in order to justify the range of the function although the previous line already explains it properly?

IMO the author's intent is to specify that the range is exactly $[0, \infty)$ and not a proper subset of it.

@MauroALLEGRANZA isn't it already justified by the previous  lines. What was the need of the quoted line?

Agreed; $\text {Ran}(f) = { y \mid \exists x (x,y) \in f }$. Thus, $-1 \notin \text {Ran }(f)$.
